# Postgres - disable autovacuum for a list of tables

Tags: postgresql

I need to disable autovacuum for a list of tables within a particular schema on Postgress.
How to do this  programmatically
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME SET (autovacuum_enabled = false);

Comment: Why do you think you "need" to do that? Disabling auto-vacuum is almost always a really bad idea

Comment: The statement you show already works. How much more "programmatical" than SQL do you want to get?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I mean coding options to do this,  I'm not familiar at all with Postgres. I need to update several schemas with lot of tables.

Comment: Why do you think that you need this? Usually this is the start of massive problems and you'll be back in a few weeks or months and you need some help to recover your database. So, what is the real problem you're facing?

Comment: Use the language of your choice and run the statement against all databases. But I agree that it is probably not a good idea.